# Sending POST data from react to Django-rest -framework showing 415 error

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

when i change fetch url from django url to webhook(dummy api key) it works but when comes to `localhost` it fails.

**views.py:**

```
class postlist(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        mod = post.objects.all()
        serializer = postSerializers(mod,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        pass


class create(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = postSerializers
```

**React Component:**

```
 async postdata(){

    try{

        let result = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create',{
            method:'post',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: 'workig hohoh',
                body: 'yes'
            })
        });

        console.log('Result: ' + result)

    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}


render() {
<div>
     <button onClick={ () => this.postdata() }>post</button>
</div> 
}
}
```

when posting it is saying **415 unsopperted media type** , dont know whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

you might have APPEND_SLASH set to true as it is the default.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash

Can you try to replace your link like so `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/`?